# Navigate without showing page name in navigation bar and w/o frames

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have navigated sites where after signing in, i see the address as, for example:

```
https://examplesite.com/access
```

Once arrived, all the links on the landing page are navigable, but the corresponding address of the link never appears in the address bar.

I don't want to hide the address bar, I just don't want the page names to appear in the address bar. It is a cleaner way, instead of having the user see all the lame names of each of the web pages. To me, it just looks better.

Answer (score 0):

Download the wappalyzer extension for chrome / firefox this will help you determine what technologies are being used on the website (though not all the time).

Those sites that are not changing the url will be either utilizing React, AngularJS or another form of JS library which is pulling in data using ajax.

Hope this helps

Comment: Also i just noticed there is a related entry at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page?rq=1